# How should I write this controller/model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, cassandra

I am new to nodejs and got a task to do; The task is to INSERT data to Cassandra db with post request. But I don't know where the problem is.

Controller:

```
module.exports.add_auctionEvent = async (req, response) =>
{
apps_model.question_marks = await make_question_marks(req.body);
apps_model.columns = ['description', 'name'];
const result = await apps_model.save_auction_event(
    [req.body.description, req.body.name]
);

response.json(result);
}
```

Model:

```
this.save_auction_event = async (params) => {
        let res = await this.add(params);
        return res;
    }
```

and Add function in above model:

```
    async add(params) {
    var query = `INSERT INTO ${this.table} (${this.columns}) VALUES (${this.question_marks})`;
    await db.execute(query, params, {prepare: true})
        .catch((e) => {
            this.error = e
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.result = res
        })
    return this.error || {status: true}
}
```

It gives me this cassandra error:

```
{
"name": "ResponseError",
"info": "Represents an error message from the server",
"message": "Unmatched column names/values",
"code": 8704,
"query": "INSERT INTO auction_event (description,name) VALUES (?)"}
```

I tested GET request and worked, so there is not any problem with db or sth.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: your "make question marks" variable should return "?,?" instead of just "?",,,thats the issue

Comment: Column names must match values. You can not use 2 columns and only 1 value. You need to have "INSERT INTO auction_event (description,name) VALUES (?, ?)"

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Thanks I'll work on it tommorow, I think the problem is with loop that creates question marks.